# Incorrectly grabbing elements with Physics.RaycastAll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a tetris-like game, now I'm trying to check if there are 10 blocks left on the line where the block fell (in this case) so I can remove them and add points.

My script runs with a weird delay except for the blocks that just fell (all the other ones that fell earlier counts).
It happens, however, that the sent RaycastAll will correctly catch all blocks in a given line, but it is quite rare and random.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckBlocksRow : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool check;
public List<float> blocksHeight = new List<float>();

public int blocksInRow;
public GameObject[] caughtBlocks;
public LayerMask layerMask;

RaycastHit[] hittedBlocks;

void Update()
{
    if (check)
    {
        blocksHeight.Sort();

        for (int i = 0; i < blocksHeight.Count; i++)
        {
            if (SendLaser(blocksHeight[i])) CheckBlocks();
        }
    }
}

bool SendLaser(float heightToCheck)
{
    RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(new Vector2(-5.78f, heightToCheck), transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right), Mathf.Infinity, layerMask);
    blocksInRow = hits.Length;

    if (blocksInRow >= 1)
    {
        hittedBlocks = hits;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        check = false;
        return false;
    }
}

void CheckBlocks()
{
    caughtBlocks = new GameObject[0];
    caughtBlocks = new GameObject[hittedBlocks.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < caughtBlocks.Length; i++)
    {
        caughtBlocks[i] = hittedBlocks[i].transform.gameObject;
    }

    if (caughtBlocks.Length == 10) print("Full row: " + caughtBlocks[0].transform.position.y);

    check = false;
}
}
```

The script is run as soon as the current block that is about to fall finally falls. Then the script that divides it into smaller parts is run, but it does not run the script of the earlier script.

```
void SetToCheck()
{
    CheckBlocksRow _checkBlocksRow = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Board").transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<CheckBlocksRow>();
    _checkBlocksRow.blocksHeight.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        if(transform.GetChild(i).name != "Center") _checkBlocksRow.blocksHeight.Add(transform.GetChild(i).transform.position.y);
    }

    _checkBlocksRow.check = true;
}
```

[image]

In this picture, the script on the first line only caught 8 blocks out of the 10 that are there.

Comment: Physics tends to be quite fickle. There could be many points of failure. The determined block height might be rounded weirdly, combined with small collider boxes and the fact that you cast the ray in a direction relative to the rotation of the board might make the ray miss. Personally I would completely avoid raycasting for Tetris. It would be much easier to use a 2d bool array.

Comment: I agree that it would be easier and that's what I wanted to do at first, but in my concept there are 3 ways to play:
1: The standard gameplay that everyone knows from tetris
2: Building the highest building possible (here comes the problem of why I gave up doing bool array, during a longer game, this would become very resource-intensive)
3: Game for time

Comment: Not completely sold on the second game mode (the source of all your troubles) sounds like spamming blocks in the middle, but would also be possible to use a dictionary with a row key and a cell enum value. It would not be dissimilar to what you're already doing. Only drawback would be a massive lag spike when recalculating the old rows.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to maybe not remove the error but make everything work with a slight delay.

```
private IEnumerator Delay()
{
    print("before");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    print("after");

    for (int i = 0; i < blocksHeight.Count; i++)
    {
        if (SendLaser(blocksHeight[i])) CheckBlocks();
    }
}
```